# How to make QDialogButtonBox NOT close its parent QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I have a QDialog with a QDialogButtonBox widget, and I've connected the button box's accepted signal to a slot in my QDialog subclass, like so:

```
void MyDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QString errorString = this->inputErrorString();
    if (errorString.isEmpty())
    {
        // Do work here
        // code code code...

        this->accept();
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("The following input errors have occurred:") + errorString);
    }
}
```

However, the dialog is closes after the message box is displayed; apparently the button box automatically connects its accepted signal to QDialog's accept slot (I want to call that slot manually). How can I prevent this so I can take the manual approach outlined above?

Comment: The question seems to be obscure, can you make a sample example and post the full code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement MyDialog::accept(). The function is virtual in [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept).

Comment: Call QDialog::accept(); inside this overloaded function to accept or return; to keep the dialog running.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding MyDialog::accept(), I was able to accomplish this by disconnecting the default accepted() and rejected() signals in the QDialog constructor like this:

```
ui->buttonBox->disconnect(SIGNAL(accepted()), this);
ui->buttonBox->disconnect(SIGNAL(rejected()), this);
```